# How to change navbar title dynamically react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to change my navbar title to log out after I logged in, however, my auth check function is in my login component class, how can I link them up as this nav is not a component itself.

```
import React from 'react';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => (

  <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
    <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">Home</Link>
    <div className="collpase navbar-collapse">
      <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li className="navbar-item">
        <Link to="/login" className="nav-link">{}</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="navbar-item">
        <Link to="/Signup" className="nav-link">Sign up</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
);

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the state that holds the logging data in high place so you could pass the data to all the components below it.

redux makes it much easier.